# Are there limits to tidy evaluation scope?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm trying to use tidy evaluation, as defined in [`dplyr 0.7.0`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/).

However, during a function call within `mutate()` I am getting an error. It seems that the variables are not being evaluated as I expect.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

myCor <- function(col1, col2) {
  col1 <- enquo(col1)
  col2 <- enquo(col2)

  mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("vehicle") %>%
    select(vehicle, !!col1, !!col2) %>%
    mutate(correlation=cor(!!col1, !!col2))
}

myCor("mpg", "disp")
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#   Evaluation error: 'x' must be numeric.
```

Instead, I have to use this non-tidy eval syntax to get the desired output.

```
myCor <- function(col1, col2) {
  col1_tidy <- enquo(col1)
  col2_tidy <- enquo(col2)

  mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("vehicle") %>%
    select(vehicle, !!col1_tidy, !!col2_tidy) %>%
    mutate(correlation=cor(eval(parse(text=col1)), eval(parse(text=col2))))
}

myCor("mpg", "disp")
# vehicle  mpg  disp correlation
# 1            Mazda RX4 21.0 160.0  -0.8475514
# 2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0 160.0  -0.8475514
# 3           Datsun 710 22.8 108.0  -0.8475514
# 4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4 258.0  -0.8475514
# ...
```

Is there a way to use tidy evaluation throughout this example?

Comment: Call your first function with this `myCor(mpg, disp)` (no quotes needed, that's the fun with nse :) )

Comment: Comapre `myCor(mpg, disp)` to `myCor("mpg", "disp")` The quotes make a big difference. With them you have a character value, without them you have symbols. NSE usually assumes you have symbols.

Comment: If you you do need to convert strings to character values to symbols, it's better to use `as.name()` or `rlang::sym()` rather than `parse(text=))`

Comment: Thanks. I can see that the quoting makes a difference when I have the `cor()` function call. But if you omit the `mutate()` line, the `select()` call behaves identically with strings or NSE expressions. Why is this?

Comment: `select` can handle strings as inputs, `mutate` can't - it expect "bare" column names that are mutated.  `select` is more flexible there

Comment: `rlang::sym()` can handle both strings and bare column names, which is a nice bonus over `quo` and `enquo`. Looks like `select` is using `sym` or its plural form `syms` and `mutate` is using `enquo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ensym` instead of `enquo` if you want to pass strings as your arguments...

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(tibble)

myCor <- function(col1, col2) {
  col1 <- ensym(col1)
  col2 <- ensym(col2)

  mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("vehicle") %>%
    select(vehicle, !!col1, !!col2) %>%
    mutate(correlation=cor(!!col1, !!col2))
}

# both of these will work now
myCor("mpg", "disp")
myCor(mpg, disp)
```

Comment: CRAN version of `dplyr` imports `rlang`, so I don't think that's technically neccesary

Answer (score 1):

From the vignette [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html):

> Most dplyr arguments are not referentially transparent. That means you can’t replace a value with a seemingly equivalent object that you’ve defined elsewhere.

Therefore you need to pass the unquoted column names to the function, as then with `enquo` the environment is captured properly and the `!!` returns the unquoted column names as `mutate` expects it.

To turn a normal `mutate`-call into a function with non-standard evaluation it might be more intuitive to start like this.
First write down the call as you would do without the function:

```
mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("vehicle") %>%
    select(vehicle, mpg, disp) %>%
    mutate(correlation = cor(mpg, disp))
```

This works (and would raise an error with quoted `mpg` and `disp`!).
Now pull the variables, you'd like to vary in front of the call and substitute them:

```
col1 <- quo(mpg)
col2 <- quo(disp)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("vehicle") %>%
  select(vehicle, !!col1, !!col2) %>%
  mutate(correlation=cor(!!col1, !!col2))
```

As this is outside of a function we have to use `quo` here, but in the last step, when we wrap it in a function we use `enquo`.

```
myCor <- function(var1, var2) {
  col1 <- enquo(var1)
  col2 <- enquo(var2)

  mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("vehicle") %>%
    select(vehicle, !!col1, !!col2) %>%
    mutate(correlation=cor(!!col1, !!col2))
}
```

I used different names for the function arguments and then the "quoted" object (with `enquo`) to make the distinction clearer, but of course it works with `col1` and `col2` as well.